# ASPupload 'if Not File Is Nothing' always returns false

Tags: asp-classic

Using [Persits ASPupload component](http://www.aspupload.com/) to upload and process files (Classic ASP).

The file is being uploaded via a jQuery ajax form.

I have run into an odd situation, where the customary test `if Not File Is Nothing Then` always returns `false` even when the file has most definitely been uploaded (I can see it on the server).

This is my jQuery code:

```
    var hiddenSignature = $("#hiddenSignature").val();

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('closingPic', $('#closingPic')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('hiddenSignature',hiddenSignature);

    $.ajax({ 

        url: "ajax_tickets_file.asp?action=cost", 
        type: "POST", 
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,     
        data: formData, 

        beforeSend: function() {
            ...
        },
        success: function(msg) { 
            ...
       }
    });
```

And this is the server side code on **ajax_tickets_file.asp**:

```
   Set objUpload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload.1")

    With objUpload

       .CodePage = 65001
       .OverwriteFiles = False

       Set file = .Files("closingPic")

       .SaveVirtual defaultUploadsFolder  // a file is indeed saved on the server, at the correct location 
       response.write " saved  "

       if Not file Is Nothing Then
            response.write “we have a file” 
        else
             response.write "no file"   //  this is what I get
        end if
```

So, as mentioned earlier, I get “no file” printed.

How could this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H/T to the owner of Persits ASPupload for helping me

Code should be:

```
   .CodePage = 65001
   .OverwriteFiles = False

   //these 2 lines should be in reversed order: 'save' before 'set file'
   .SaveVirtual defaultUploadsFolder   
   Set file = .Files("closingPic")
```